# How to variables from a textfile into a C# script

Tags: text-files

I need to create a text file for a game designer to edit variables in my C# script. I would like to be able to write the variable in the text file and the designer can put in a value and hten it would change in my script.

However, after much searching I have not been able to find a solution to my problem and was hoping someone with some experience in this method could help me.

I'm using Visual Studio for writing my scripts and the designer would require Notepad.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Hi Chris... errr... have you considered just reading the file ... have you done any programming before? This is the SIMPLEST of functions. I am surprised you can't find any answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using this class that will allow you to use `ini` files to hold your configuration.

I'm assuming your designer wouldn't like to use XML (which is the .NETy way of doing things); making humans edit XML is a form of torture anyway.

Here's the link to the CodeProject page: [An INI file handling class using C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1966/An-INI-file-handling-class-using-C).

You can also use some other (relatively simple) format like JSON if `ini` files are too flat for you.